# How do I cycle through an object and it's nested objects before moving on to the next object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cocoon-gem

I'm a beginner at RoR.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to cycle through a list of `service_types` *(brakes, drums, pads, etc...)* per `service` category *(brakes)* belonging to each tech before going on to the next `service` category *(suspension)*.

I have a setup with the following:

Gems 
`devise: user signup`
`cocoon: customizable nested objects`

My view from my services/show.html.erb

```
<tbody>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= service.name %></td>
        <td><%= **??? Don't know how to cycle through to capture the tech's list `services` and `service types**` %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

---

**service.rb model**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_types
    belongs_to :tech

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_types, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

---

**techs_controller.rb**

```
class TechsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @techs = Tech.all
    @services = Service.all

  end

  def show
    @tech = Tech.find(params[:id])
    @services = @tech.services.all
    #@service_types = @service.service_types.all
  end
end
```

---

**tech.rb** model (db with list of techs - registered via `devise` gem)

```
class Tech < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :service_types
  has_many :services
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :customers, :through => :appointments
end
```

---

> **Edited - 5/25 [Reason: copy paste error / typo]**

Service (contains data with a list of services main categories)

```
mysql> describe services;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tech_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `tech_id` references a record in the `tech` db

ServiceType (from the cocoon gem which allows me to create nested service types with several custom attributes)

```
mysql> describe service_types;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| time        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| decimal     | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| service_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `service_id` references a record in the `services` db

---

After days of researching, the closest I've come to accomplishing what I wanted was this from my view:

```
<tbody>
    <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= service.name %></td>
        <td><%= service.service_types.all.collect{|s| [s.name, s.time, s.price} %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The above produces this:

`Brakes  [["Rotors", 1HR], ["Drums", 1HR]]`

What I'm looking for this to output is the following:

Below is the output I'm looking for:

```
+---------+----------+-----+-------+
| Brakes  | Type   | Time  | Price |
+---------+--------+-------+-------+
          | Rotors | 1HR   | 100   |
          | Drums  | 1HR   | 100   |

+-------------+----------+-----+-------+
| Suspension  | Type   | Time  | Price |
+-------------+--------+-------+-------+
              | Struts | 2HR   | 100   |
              | Shocks | 1HR   | 100   |
```

I would like to cycle through a `service` *(brakes)* and all of it's nested `service_types` before moving on to cycling through the next `service` category *(suspension)*. The

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: is what's `service`?  can you post it's definition?

Comment: My apologies, I've added the service model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= service.name %></td>
        <td>
          <table>
             <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Time</th>
               <th>Price</th>
             </tr>
             <% service.service_types.each do |service_type| %>
               <tr>
                <td><%= service_type.name %></td>
                <td><%= service_type.time %></td>
                <td><%= service_type.price %></td>
               </tr>
             <%end%> 
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

And one more thing

> service_type_id

is not required in Service table.

Comment: Thank you so much @pardeep-dhingra ! I could've sworn I did something similar to this but was receiving errors. I corrected my post to your `service_type_id` comment.

Comment: @captainawesome is it done and this solution worked?